# How an i make an ASP.NET MVC3 DisplayTemplate which displays the contents of a Collection?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, display-templates

I'm trying to display the contents of a collection, in my View .. but using a `DisplayTemplate` to handle the definition of the view, for that specialized property/object.

eg.

```
<div class="display-label">Foos</div>
<div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayTextFor(_ => Model.Foos)</div>
```

and the foo object is..

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Blah { get; set; }
}
```

and...

```
public string MyModel
{
    public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set;}
}
```

So i created a folder called `DisplayTemplates`, in my View folder for this Controller.
I then added in a file called `Foo.cshtml` with the following content

```
@model MyNamespace.....Foo

@Model [@Model.Blah] @Model.Name
```

and what i have getting displayed on my view?

> > System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNamespace.....Foo]

. I've confirmed that there is at least one item in this collection.
Any ideas, folks?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when by `@Model` in your cshtml view, do you want to print the list?

Comment: I'm strongly-typing this partial view to a custom object. Eg. `MyNamspace.Entities.Foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer :)

I (incorrectly had)

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(_ => Model.Foos)
```

but I should NOT have been using `DisplayTextFor` but `DisplayFor`

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Model.Foos)
```

Also, I have purchased copy of [Steve Sanderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615998/steven-sanderson)'s [Pro ASP.NET MVC2 Framework (2nd Edition)](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/06/11/pro-aspnet-mvc-2-framework/).pdf and on page 423 he says (and I sincerly hope I'm not infringing on copyright, here).

> For example, you could now render an
>   enumerable collection of Person
>   instances with a single line of view
>   markup—for example:
>
> ```
> <%:Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyPersonCollection) %>
> //This would render the Person.ascx partial once 
> //for each item in the collection.
> ```

And he was correct and this text highlighted my mistake.

Win :)

Comment: nice! Sandersons book is pretty awesome! Still haven't read all of it properly! =P

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be :

```
@model MyNamespace.....Foo

[@:Model.Blah] @:Model.Name
```

You could even use the `<text>` tag.

See Scott Gu's Post for Details:
[ASP.NET MVC 3: Razor’s @: and  syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx)

Comment: so you're suggesting that my custom DisplayTemplate is for ONE class instance ... so the fact that i'm trying to display a collection of Foo's isn't a problem .. the framework is smart enough to pick up that it should display my custom DisplayTemplate for each instance in the collection?

Comment: @Pure.Krome sorry misread your Q .. one option I can think of is having a **view** with a model `@IEnum<Foo>` and within that view you'll call the **view** with a model `Foo`